# Zurb Foundation dropdown misplace

Tags: zurb-foundation

I've tried [Zurb Foundation Dropdown](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html). I've copy everything from Zurb Foundation docs but I see my dropdown unlike Foundation docs. My dropdown misplaced.

**On Foundation doc:**
[On Foundation doc http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/iy/140810073919.png](http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/iy/140810073919.png)

**My page:**

[My page http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/ic/140810073900.png](http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/ic/140810073900.png)

Here is my test code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
            <!-- Dropdown -->
            <a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1">Has Dropdown</a>
            <ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
                <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the problem ?I test the code, he works like a charm. It's probably our own css who mess up the dropdown. live example http://jsbin.com/padig/1/edit

Comment: I test this code but it doesn't work correctly.

http://image.free.in.th/v/2013/iv/140810093744.PNG

Comment: My css and js download from http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html

Comment: I found solution. Replace [Foundation 5.3.3](http://foundation.zurb.com/cdn/releases/foundation-5.3.3.zip) with older version [5.3.1](http://foundation.zurb.com/cdn/releases/foundation-5.3.1.zip). It work fine.

Comment: I just want to mention that if one does not uses the ´foundation.min.js´ - the dropdown plugin (´foundation.dropdown.js´) is not included.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the reference to the dropdown js

```
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js"></script>
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/dropdown.html

Comment: I'm using Foundation 6, but the file `foundation.dropdown.js` is not in the download on http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/...where can it be found?

Comment: The version of foundation this question was for was 5. However you can find v6+ on github here https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/js/foundation.dropdown.js

Comment: Ok, this may be my ignorance, but when adding that file to my website, I'm getting this error `foundation.dropdown.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`. Is this a special js file for which I need to add something else?

Comment: Since this is for another version maybe opening a new question with the details will help